# Stacks in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I just started learning Terraform (TF) with AWS and didn't get the idea how to create a few stages infrastructure. I compare TF with Cloudformation (CF).
My first stage is to create ECS cluster with all stuff like vpc, igw, ec2s, subnets, loadbalancers, autoscaling groups and etc. Later, I plan to create independent stages that will add tasks to the cluster. So, the next stacks need to get the resources' parameters from the first stack.

In CF, I can create a few new independent stacks, which might use resources created in the first stack by using the first stack's name as a parameter.

In TF, How can I refer to the resources created in the first stack?

Comment: You would use data sources to fetch IDs. There's data sources to directly query VPCs etc but you can also output things to your state and use the `terraform_remote_state` data source if there isn't a first class data source for the data you want. In your case however if you are just adding ECS services in the second step you only need to look up the load balancer and listener so you can add a target group to it and then attached the ECS service to the target group. This would be the `aws_lb` and `aws_lb_listener` data sources.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR your comment would be better as a full answer :)

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I totally agree with @mcfinnigan, the answer is correct. `terraform_remote_state` is a good solution